# why twitter and facebook don't redirect to amp pages?

Tags: facebook, twitter, accelerated-mobile-page

I've done amp pages(validation ok) but twitter and facebook redirect to a usual page instead of amp. Should I somewhere turn on this option in tw and fb?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter supports AMP if the pages are annotated with AMP discovery tags. This means that you will need to include a `link rel="amphtml"` tag. You can check the Twitter documentation on AMP [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/publisher-tools/amp/overview).